# Sencha Touch Horizontally Center Search Field in Navigation Bar

Tags: html, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

This question is pretty downright dumb and I might have stumbled upon a bug but I need to center my searchfield in my navigation bar in Sencha Touch and I just can't make it work. This is my code:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.MyNav', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

xtype: 'mynav',

requires: [
    'Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.Button'
],

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
        navigationBar: {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    placeHolder: 'Search...',
                    listeners: {
                        keyup: function(field) {

                        }
                    },
                    align: 'right'
                }
            ]
        },

    items: [ 
        {
            title: 'MyNav',
            xtype: 'list',
            fullscreen: true,
            grouped: true,


            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'html'],
                sorters: 'name',
                data: [
                    {name: 'Alfa', html: '<p>alfa</p>'},
                    {name: 'Beta', html: '<p>beta</p>'},
                    {name: 'Gamma', html: '<p>gamma</p>'},
                    {name: 'Mupp', html: '<p>mupp</p>'},
                    {name: 'Tupp', html: '<p>tupp</p>'}
                ],
                grouper: {
                groupFn: function(record) {
                    return record.get('name')[0];
                },
                indexBar: true
            },
            },

            listeners: {
                select: function(view, record) {
                    var test = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {                        fullscreen: true,
                        title: record.get('name'),
                        layout: {
                            type:'vbox'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                html: record.get('html')
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                    var mainnav = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('bookmarksmainnav')[0];
                    mainnav.setActiveItem(test);
                }
            },

            itemTpl: '{name}'
        }
    ]
}

});
```

Focus on the actual navigation bar thing, the other stuff is just code pasted (and I modified it somewhat), I'm pretty sure this is a bug though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using a toolbar docked in the bottom of the page with the search field centered, I don't know why but the navigation bar ignores the centered property.

Something like this:

```
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    navigationBar: {

    },

    items: [ 
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    placeHolder: 'Search...',
                    listeners: {
                        keyup: function(field) {

                        }
                    },
                    centered: true
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            title: 'MyNav',
            xtype: 'list',
```

If you need the search field on the top of the screen you could try hiding the navigation bar with `hidden: true` and changing the `docked` property in the toolbar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've decided to change my whole UI, but thanks for the answer, it's working now with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer (for me) that just centres whatever you have added to the navigation bar, is:

```
this.getNavigationBar().leftBox.setCentered(true);
```

You will probably want to manage the centred-ness of the navigation bar for each page, though.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
layout: {
    align: 'center',
    pack: 'center',
    type: 'hbox'
}
```

This would be just under the docked: 'bottom', line is the example above.

Regards

Jacko

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I find it difficult to center a desired field, I just add a spacer before and after, combined with a flex for the item I want to center, it never fails. In this case:

```
      items: [
            {
                xtype: 'spacer',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Search...',
                listeners: {
                    keyup: function(field) {

                    }
               flex: 0.7

             },
            {
                xtype: 'spacer',
            },
```